# Run Jasmine tests written in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jasmine, systemjs

I have a Typescript+Node+Angular2+Electron app and currently trying to run tests for node classes, written also in Typescript.

For building the application and running it within electron I use following tsconfig:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "system",
    "target": "es6",
    ...
  }
```

So as you can see, it's using systemjs and compiling TS into JS-es6. It works fine, application itself is working.

Now I need Jasmine to come on board. I installed this npm package, updated my gulp tasks to run gulp-jasmine for just 1 file:

```
gulp.task('jasmine', function() {
    gulp.src('./test/test.js')
        .pipe(jasmine())
});
```

This is how my test.js looks like:

```
System.register(["./models-src/app/models/pathWatch/pathWatch"], function(exports_1, context_1) {
    "use strict";
    var __moduleName = context_1 && context_1.id;
    var pathWatch_1;
    return {
        setters:[
            function (pathWatch_1_1) {
                pathWatch_1 = pathWatch_1_1;
            }],
        execute: function() {
            describe("Run Application:", () => {
                it("starts", () => {
                    var pw1 = new pathWatch_1.PathWatch();
                    expect(true).toEqual(true);
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

So, nothing special, 1 import-1test-1assert, wrapped with SystemJs stuff. 
When I try to run this test, I have an error: "System is not defined".

My questions are:

1) Is it possible to run jasmine tests, using systemjs loader inside?

2) If it's possible, do I need to install/configure some additional stuff?

3) I tried to compile TS using Module="commonjs" and it's working. But I don't want to compile my source differently for tests and build. Why it's working fine with commonjs without any additional manipulations?

4) Also I tried to compile TS using Module="es6". It's not working, I have an error "Unexpected reserved word". Is it possible to run jasmine tests written in js es6 without transpiling them into es5?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please limit questions on [so] to one question per question. Asking multiple ones in a single post makes it harder to vote on the question, as well as the answers.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Is it possible to run jasmine tests, using systemjs loader inside?
>
> 2) If it's possible, do I need to install/configure some additional
>   stuff?

You mean, run jasmine tests in node using systemjs as a loader? I don't think jasmine supports using systemjs instead of `require` for loading modules. So your tests need to be in commonjs, but test code can use SystemJS to load and test application code. Something like this in `test.js` could work, provided that systemjs is configured properly and can find pathWatch module:

```
describe("Run Application:", () => {
    it("starts", (done) => {

        var system = require('systemjs');
        system.config({
           // systemjs config here
           // 
        });
        system.import('path-to-path-watch-module').then(pathWatch => {
            var pw = new pathWatch.PathWatch();
            expect(true).toEqual(true);
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

system.import is asynchronous, so all jasmine tests need to be [async](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support) too.

> 3) I tried to compile TS using Module="commonjs" and it's working. But
>   I don't want to compile my source differently for tests and build. Why
>   it's working fine with commonjs without any additional manipulations?

Because then there is no reference to System in the compiled code - it uses `module.exports` like any other node module and can be loaded as is by jasmine.

> 4) Also I tried to compile TS using Module="es6". It's not working, I
>   have an error "Unexpected reserved word". Is it possible to run
>   jasmine tests written in js es6 without transpiling them into es5?

`Module="es6"` requires a runtime that supports es6 `import` and `export`, so it needs a transpiler and module loader before it can run on current version of node.